# Gulp bundle only if source files changed

Tags: gulp

I'm pretty new to gulp, so hopefully this is an easy one.

I'm trying to genereate a number of bundles, each of which will be composed of a bunch of js/css files (sourced from a file), but I only want to build each bundle if any of it's source files changed.

My starting code looks like the following. What do I need to add to make it work?

```
gulp.task('bundle', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(sourceFile)
        .pipe(bundle())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDest))
        .pipe(bundle.results({
            pathPrefix: '/bundlePath/',
            dest: manifestDest
        }));
});
```

sourceFile:

```
module.exports = {
    bundle: {
        "bundle1": {
            "scripts": [
                "file1.js",
                "file2.js",
                "file3.js"
            ],
            "styles": "style1.css"      
        },
        "bundle2": {
            "scripts": [
                "file1.js",
                "file4.js"
            ],
            "styles": [         
                "style1.css",
                "style2.css"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For example, if only file1.js changes, I want both bundle1 and bundle2 rebuilt since they share file1.js. If only file4.js changes, only bundle2 should be rebuilt.

This process is kicked off when the release version of the project is built in VS2012.

I looked into alternative packages like gulp-changed, but they seem to only work with single files (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: use gulp-watch.. to was specific set of files //bundle, and call the bundling task as part of gulp-watch

Comment: bundle() takes file1.js - file3.js under bundle1/scripts and puts them all into 1 file. Same for the other groupings as well, even if there is only 1 file as in bundle1/styles

@entre Can you give me an example? I forgot to mention that this script runs once the release version of the project compiles. I've added this to the original.